# mysqli_query() dentro de mysqli_fetch_assoc() dispensa o uso de mysqli_free_result?

Tags: php, mysqli

Com a nova classe do MySQL, a `mysqli`, tornou-se necessário nos preocuparmos em sempre fazer o uso de `mysqli_free_result()` após `mysqli_query()` com `SELECT` para liberação de memória, porém eu muitas vezes uso `mysqli_query()` dentro de `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` e neste caso não tenho uma variável com o resultado de `mysqli_query()`.

O que eu gostaria de saber é se este meu procedimento pode levar ao uso indevido de memória, ou seja, se tenho realmente que fazer um código para usar `mysqli_free_result()` ou não? Veja exemplo:

COM o uso de `mysqli_free_result()`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM .... LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

SEM o uso de `mysqli_free_result()`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM .... LIMIT 1";
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $query));
mysqli_close($conn);
</pre>
```

Comment: Eu diria que não devias usar a função diretamente na `mysqli_fetch_assoc`...

Comment: colocar um função dentro da outra função seria um erro, o bom é que cada linha execute separadamente determinada função, o debug e a manutenção agradecem nesse estilo.... !!! o `mysqli_free_result` também existia no antigo `mysql` http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-free-result.php